# selenium-standalone-chrome throws error when driver is trying to connect

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My goal is to run Selenium in a docker. The problem is that it refused to connect although selenium-standalone-chrome works fine and I can hit http://127.0.0.1:4444 in my own browser.

The culrpit:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    options=chrome_options
)
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1047, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 911, in run_command
    raise e from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 897, in run_command
    app = info.load_app()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 308, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Volumes/T7Touch/Learn/p2---final-project-ftds-016-rmt-group-001/scraping-2/deployment/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from util.scrapeutil import get_db
  File "/Volumes/T7Touch/Learn/p2---final-project-ftds-016-rmt-group-001/scraping-2/deployment/util/scrapeutil.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: '07a1292de76f', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.7.1', revision: 'c6795baf1a3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.124-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.7.1', revision: 'c6795baf1a3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.124-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply (DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply (DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply (SessionSlot.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession (LocalNode.java:379)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.startSession (LocalDistributor.java:645)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession (LocalDistributor.java:564)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.handleNewSessionRequest (LocalDistributor.java:818)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.lambda$run$1 (LocalDistributor.java:779)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
```

Edit: I use Mac M1. So I should use `docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" seleniarm/standalone-chromium` instead of `docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" seleniarm/standalone-chromium`

Comment: Where is your python code running?

Comment: @AlexeyR. the python code is running a scraper for our final project, it's a Flask app with pandas, gunicorn. The repository https://github.com/H8-Assignments-Bay/p2---final-project-ftds-016-rmt-group-001/blob/SCRAPING-2/scraping-2/scrapeutil.py (haven't push the latest commit, as I still can't figure out how to run selenium on docker). We intended to use selenium to get the data for our NLP model to do sentiment analysis per day.

Comment: I mean if you are running it inside a container or at your host machine?

Comment: @AlexeyR. the problem is my computer is a Mac Mini M1. I just found out selenium/standalone-chrome is not compatible with arm64. I intended to download seleniumarm (downloading as we speak).

Comment: @AlexeyR. currently at my host machine. The host machine is Mac Mini M1. The server will be intel.